# Cannot login to server after disabling SELinux

Tags: centos, selinux

I changed the following file in centos

```
/etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

and set it as

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

and run the `reboot` command.

but now I cannot login to my server. It shows the error

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

when I login as a *user* and *password*.

How can I get back into my server.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling SELinux and rebooting seems to set the `UsePAM` option in your sshd_config to `no` which explicitly does not work in RHEL:

`# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several problems`

If you are able to detach and access the volume externally, you can set this back to `yes` and should be able to ssh in again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got the solution.

when I login with domain after disabling SELinux lets say

```
ssh user@domain
```

I cannot login even with correct password

but I can login as

```
ssh user@ip
```

I don't know the reason but this actually worked for me.